# Two way binding direct to DataContext

Tags: wpf, binding

I've a custom control I'm working on that presents a list of ComboBoxes inside an ItemsControl. The ItemsControl is bound to a list of int and so the DataContext for each ComboBox is just an int. This is bound to the SelectedIndex, and the list of items is brought from elsewhere. The ItemsControl is defined as

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsCtl" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedSourceIndices}"
              Grid.Row="1">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <util:BindingProxy x:Key="parent" Data="{Binding}" />
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource parent},Path=Data.SourceFieldNames}"
                      SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=DataContext, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                            Mode=TwoWay,
                            diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This initially looks fine, but I've discovered that when you click on a ComboBox and change the selection, the change isn't propagated to the underlying List.

I did have difficulty initially getting this binding to work, since there's no Path, and found out how [here.](http://rredcat.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/this-whimsical-binding-twoway-binding.html) However, figuring that the first place to look would be this weird binding directly to the context, I modified it to instead bind to a list of IntContainer, being a class that just contains a single int property. This works fine, but it's messy.

Although there's no errors, even with full tracing of the binding, I do see a difference in diagnostic output. The bulk of it's unwieldy, but on changing a value using the straight int I see

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 90 : BindingExpression (hash=20081636): Update - got raw value '3'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 93 : BindingExpression (hash=20081636): Update - implicit converter produced '3'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 94 : BindingExpression (hash=20081636): Update - using final value '3'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 102 : BindingExpression (hash=20081636): SetValue at level 0 to ComboBox (hash=64451636) using DependencyProperty(DataContext): '3'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=20081636): GetValue at level 0 from ComboBox (hash=64451636) using DependencyProperty(DataContext): '3'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=20081636): TransferValue - got raw value '3'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 84 : BindingExpression (hash=20081636): TransferValue - implicit converter produced '3'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=20081636): TransferValue - using final value '3'
```

and on changing a value when using IntContainer I see

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 90 : BindingExpression (hash=35938393): Update - got raw value '1'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 94 : BindingExpression (hash=35938393): Update - using final value '1'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 102 : BindingExpression (hash=35938393): SetValue at level 0 to IntContainer (hash=56037929) using ReflectPropertyDescriptor(Value): '1'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=35938393): Got ValueChanged event from IntContainer (hash=56037929)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=35938393): GetValue at level 0 from IntContainer (hash=56037929) using ReflectPropertyDescriptor(Value): '1'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=35938393): TransferValue - got raw value '1'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=35938393): TransferValue - using final value '1'
```

So it looks like the way I've got the binding set up, when using the straight int, is getting the correct values initially but is then writing the changes back to the ComboBox itself, and not to the backing array. Which is weird and, of course, pointless.

Does anyone know how to change the binding so it updates the value in the List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SelectedIndex is bound to an object and not a property of an object. When it changes, the new value is a completely different object than the old object - you can't change an object to another object (variables/properties yes, objects no). And this new object is not in your array.

You'll need to convert your list of ints to a list of objects that has an int. You are using BindingProxy already so you could convert it to a list of those and update the SelectedIndex binding.

If you really want to keep your list of ints though, you'll need to use something else as a proxy. In the code below, I used a converter to convert the list of ints to a list of a new class 'IntProxy'.

Here is the entire test case I made for your issue:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication32.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication32"
        xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <local:IntProxyConverter x:Key="IntProxyConverter" />
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <StackPanel.DataContext>
            <local:VM />
        </StackPanel.DataContext>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsCtl" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedSourceIndices, Converter={StaticResource IntProxyConverter}}">
            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <local:BindingProxy x:Key="parent" Data="{Binding}" />
            </ItemsControl.Resources>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource parent},Path=Data.SourceFieldNames}"
                            SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=Value,
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                Mode=TwoWay,
                                diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding AsString}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

CS:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication32
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<int> SelectedSourceIndices { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<int>(new int[] { 5, 3, 6, 1, 0, 2, 4 });
        public string[] SourceFieldNames { get; set; } = new string[] { "S0", "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7" };


        // The rest of this class is just to visualize the above properties in realtime
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public string AsString
        {
            get {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var s in SelectedSourceIndices)
                    sb.AppendFormat("int = {0}", s).AppendLine();
                foreach (var s in SourceFieldNames)
                    sb.AppendFormat("name = {0}", s).AppendLine();
                return sb.ToString();
            }
        }

        public VM()
        {
            SelectedSourceIndices.CollectionChanged += SelectedSourceIndices_CollectionChanged;
        }

        private void SelectedSourceIndices_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AsString"));
        }
    }

    public class IntProxyConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var src = value as Collection<int>;
            var col = new ObservableCollection<IntProxy>();
            if (src != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < src.Count(); i++)
                {
                    col.Add(new IntProxy() { Index = i, Source = src });
                }
            }
            return col;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class IntProxy : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int Value { get { return Source.ElementAt(Index); } set { if (Source[Index] != value) { Source[Index] = value; OPC("Value"); } } }
        public int Index { get; set; } // This shouldn't be changing
        public Collection<int> Source { get; set; } // This shouldn't be changing either

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OPC(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public class BindingProxy : Freezable
    {
        #region Overrides of Freezable

        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
        {
            return new BindingProxy();
        }

        #endregion

        public object Data
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks- far more detailed and complete than I expected. :)